# Unfortunately App Stopped While Saving Parse Objects onto cloud

Tags: android, parse-platform, sdk

```
package com.example.root.sportdb;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.parse.*;
import com.parse.ParseObject;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "lG75j5BVA3Y7K7HubpV2wMC3D5sJ9cP2mQnryYUy", "Ht2LOvXISgvZkaoMl1WQRzFup4NkF2GznKSO7j3D");

        addListenerOnButton();
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPush);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            EditText id,name,email,phone;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                      ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
                    id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtID);
                name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
                phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
                testObject.put("ID",id);

                testObject.saveInBackground();




            }
            });
        }
    }
```

hey I am new to Parse integration via Android SDK app, trying to save a Id, Name,Phone and email onto my one of the class on parse data.  Whenever I run this app  testObject.put("ID",id); appplication throws an error "Unfortnatley application  failed ok" and parse data gets a blank on the parse data.

Comment: put your logs here...

Comment: This should be  `testObject.put("ID",id);` should be  `testObject.put("ID",id.getText().toString());` cause the docs says **Values may be numerical, String, JSONObject, JSONArray, JSONObject.NULL, or other ParseObjects. value may not be null.**

Answer (score 0):

You should try to save a String but not an EditText.

```
testObject.put("ID",id.getText().toString());
```